# How do I change the database owner in Synapse Analytics Serverless SQL Pool?

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse-analytics

I am working with Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pool. A former employee created the databases in the pool, and is listed as their owner. Consequently, I cannot drop the login.

I would like to change the owner of the databases to `[sa]`; however, all the means I know to change database owners in TSQL do not work in Serverless SQL Pool.

For instance, `sp_changedbowner` does not exist. Also, `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` is not supported. I've tried syntax that works in other non-MS databases, such as `ALTER DATABASE x OWNER TO y`, but this is not valid TSQL.

What is the proper way to change a database owner so it's not tied to a long-gone employee?

Comment: Have you tried sp_changedbowner?

Comment: Yep. As mentioned (but misspelled) in my question, that does not exist in Synapse Serverless SQL Pool.